# Is there a way to get the active tab with ngxbootstrap?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm developing an Angular app using the [ngx tabs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs#api-reference) :

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <tabset>
       <tab heading="1"></tab>
       <tab heading="2"></tab>
    </tabset>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer>
   <button *ngIf="Tab Selected = 1"> Save </button>
   <button *ngIf="Tab Selected = 2"> Update </button>
</div>
```

I would like to know on the template which tab is selected, so I can show/hide the correct buttons.

Answer (score 11):

If you follow ngx-bootstrap documentation you can see that there is an output => 'select'.

It fires when tab became active. Simply you can use this as below.

```
<div class="modal-body">
<tabset>
   <tab heading="1" (selectTab)="changeTab($event)"></tab>
   <tab heading="2" (selectTab)="changeTab($event)"></tab>
</tabset>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer>
   <button *ngIf="activeTab == 1"> Save </button>
   <button *ngIf="activeTab == 2"> Update </button>
</div>
```

Inside the component

```
public activeTab: string; 

changeTab($event) {
   this.activeTab = $event.heading;
}
```

For further:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/?gclid=CjwKCAjwlejcBRAdEiwAAbj6KTeGOBoB7Q8PwR-hC4ipYDNGQPT7pFOCVLR_pQbN2n4rBHVM6RSL_xoCgPAQAvD_BwE#/tabs

Answer (score 6):

You can get `TabsetComponent` via ViewChild and then look at its `tabs` property, there you'll find all tabs and then it will be easy to find out which one is active. There's an example of it (open a console to see a result) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wm4ywp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thanks! useful for getting active tab as well as set an active tab programatically.

Answer (score 0):

better way is to add **id** to all tab elements and check according to the id, that is:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="1" id="tab-1" (selectTab)="changeTab($event)"></tab>
    <tab heading="2" id="tab-2" (selectTab)="changeTab($event)"></tab>
</tabset>
```

Inside the component

```
changeTab($event) {
   this.activeTabId = $event?.id;
}
```

this way the tab is more consistent since we can change the **header with custom template** and id is unique.